# Power series problem. ( Complex Analysis)

Tags: complex-analysis

A function $f(z)$ has a power series representation as : $$f(z) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n (z-z_0)^{n}$$ inside some circle $|z-z_0| = R$ , we need to show that : $$(1)\:\:\:\:f^{(n)}(z) = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\dfrac{(n+k)!}{k!} a_{n+k} (z-z_0)^{k}$$  where $f^{n}(z)$ is the nth derivative of the function $f(z)$.

Also we need to show that :

$(2)$ for $z=z_0$ the coefficients $a_n$ are the coefficients in the Taylor series for $f$ about $z_0$.

I was able to prove part (1) , but got stuck in the (2).

By P.M.I we got : $$f^{(n)}(z) = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\dfrac{(n+k)!}{k!} a_{n+k} (z-z_0)^{k}$$ Replacing $n$ by $n-k$ gives :$$f^{(n-k)}(z) = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\dfrac{(n)!}{k!} a_{n} (z-z_0)^{k}$$

Now differentiating $k$ times gives : $$f^{(n)}(z) ={n!} a_n$$ which gives :$$\dfrac{f^{(n)}(z)}{n!} = a_n$$ but in order to prove (2) we should get $$\dfrac{f^{(n)}(z_0)}{n!} = a_n$$ Am I neglecting something ? Could anyone help ?

Comment: If you differentiate $f^{(n-k)}$ $k$ times you get $f^{(n-2k)}$, no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This step makes no sense:

> Replacing $n$ by $n-k$ gives :$$f^{(n-k)}(z) = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\dfrac{(n)!}{k!} a_{n} (z-z_0)^{k}$$

$k$ is the summation index on the right-hand side and runs through all
non-negative integers, so you cannot replace $n$ by $n-k$. And
what value has $k$ on the left-hand side?

But actually it is much simpler: You only need to set $z = z_0$ in $(1)$. In the sum on the right-hand side, $(z_0 - z_0) ^k$ is zero for $k \ge 1$, and what remains is the term for $k = 0$:
$$
f^{(n)}(z_0) = n! a_n \, .
$$